# Popup displaying image on iPhone app?

Tags: ios, popup, uiimage

I want to show an image in popup view which also contains the close button.

I have searched for that but I did not found any thing about that.

Please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for popup

1) [ALPopup](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/alpopupview)
2) [BlureModelView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rnblurmodalview)
3) [Ogactionchooser](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ogactionchooser)
4) [Other](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert) and [This](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popup)

Answer (score 1):

Just try out following simple way -

You can create one `UIView` that contains `UIImageView` and `UIButton`.

Whenever you want to show the the image just assign image to the UIImageView and and show the UIView.

And when you want to hide the the image just hide the UIView on pressing UIButton `(i.e close button)`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
 UIView *contentView;
 UIImageView *dot;

 contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,350)];
 contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

  dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,40,200,200)];
  dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:"DSC_0055.JPG.jpg"];
  dot.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  [contentView addSubview: dot];
 [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:contentView    andAnimated:YES];
}
}
```

https://github.com/kgn/KGModal